# How can I sum within two sheet

Tags: excel, sum

I have two columns. Range c3:c contains the fixed value in 3rd sheet("Sus_AC"). In another 4th sheet("FR_Data") range D3:D  contains continuous value. If two range match then column 23 of FR_data will sum and set Column 7 in Sus_AC. I have the following code but this gives me no result.

```
Dim i As Long, a As Double
a = 0
For i = 3 To lastRow
If Worksheets("Sus_AC").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("FR_Data").Cells(i, 4).Value Then
a = a + Worksheets("FR_Data").Cells(i, 23).Value
End If
Worksheets("Sus_AC").Activate
Worksheets("Sus_AC").Cells(i, 3).Value = a
Next i
```

Comment: Mistake: Worksheets("Sus_AC").Cells(i, 7).Value = a

Comment: So your comment is the solution?

Comment: In the Sus_AC Sheet 7th column will be sum result if 3rd column match with FR_Data 4th column. Please help